# How to show all the products on seach result page in Magento?

Tags: php, magento-1.9

If we type any string "shoes" in search box then it shows the search results related to that string. Like below:

http://example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=shoes

And if we do not type anything in search box then it doesn't open the search result page. It redirects to home page.

http://example.com/

I want to show all the results on search result page if we submit the blank in search box.

http://example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

//Go through the below instructions and set your setting according.

```
http://www.w3bdeveloper.com/how-to/magento-search-displays-your-search-returns-no-results/
```

Comment: My search is already working. I want only show all the products on search result page when submit empty in search box.

Comment: Then you have to add custom code for blank search in the following path. magento\app\code\local\Mage\CatalogSearch\controllers\ResultController.php file also change this condition for allow blank search ex : $query->getQueryText() != ''